# For>while>for loops slowing down this R code?

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I apologize in advance for the elementary question, but thought it may be a quick pointer from someone out there.

I am looking at this publicly-available code and wondering why it runs slow (or stalls completely), when the mu for the negative binomial generation is >1. Is it related to the nested loops?

Thank you.

```
for(i in 1:runs) {
    cases <- seed
    t <- rep(0,seed)
    times <- t
    while(cases > 0) {
        secondary <- rnbinom(cases,size=fit.cases$estimate[1],mu=fit.cases$estimate[2])
        t.new <- numeric()
        for(j in 1:length(secondary)) {
            t.new <- c(t.new,t[j] + rgamma(secondary[j],shape=fit.serial$estimate[1],
                       rate=fit.serial$estimate[2]))
        }
        cases <- length(t.new)
        t <- t.new
        times <- c(times,t.new)
    }
    lines(sort(times),1:length(times),col=cols[i],lwd=1)
    points(max(times),length(times),col=cols[i],pch=16)
}
```

https://github.com/calthaus/Ebola/blob/master/Superspreading%20(Lancet%20Inf%20Dis%202015)/Ebola_superspreading_analysis.R

Comment: Your line `c(times,t.new)` is growing an object within a loop and is generally a bad idea. It is better to either pre-allocate the space for the vector prior to starting the loop, or if that is not possible then store the intermediate results in a list and binding after the loop is complete. See: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf, Chapter 2

Comment: Many thanks for pointing that out and the chapter -- I am reviewing it. If I wanted to allocate space, would that look something like (before the for loop)? :            
     times <- vector("double", 0)
     seq_along(times)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, cases should always become 0. I'll keep trying with the allocation...getting Error in times[i] <- t.new : replacement has length zero.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize that t.new could be longer than 1 element.  If that is the case make times a list: `times<-list()`, use `times[[i]]<-t.new` inside the loop and `unlist(times)` after the loop.  Note: I ran the code from the link and did not have a problem with it.  Are you greatly increasing the number of runs?

Comment: Thanks Dave, I am not increasing the runs, however, I am increasing the mu (to 2) for the negative binomial distribution. So if I run the code from github, I have no problems either, but if I try to increase mu (to 2), it stalls.

Comment: If it stalls when mu->2 then that tells me "case" is not going to zero or "secondary" is becoming very large and thus spending a long time in the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Much delayed than you for this answer -- I ended created a forced stop for "case". That worked.